# Unable to select fields on Get-ADGroupMember query

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to grab a list of users and their descriptions/departments, who are in a certain AD Security Group using the following command:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "SecurityGroup" | select samaccountname,description,department
```

This query pulls usernames (samaccountname), however is leaving blanks for description and department.
I have also tried all of the following:

```
| select-object samaccountname,description,department
| select-object -property samaccountname,description,department
| select -property samaccountname,description,department
```

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to pipe the output into a Get-ADUser to pull the additional info.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "SecurityGroup" | Get-ADUser -properties samaccountname, department, description | format-table samaccountname, department, description | Out-File SecurityGroup.txt
```